# Splitting a single file into multiple files based on matching strings in Linux

Tags: text-processing, awk, split

I have a file which has contents something like this:

File.txt:

```
661###############20160315###
###########################
###########################
661###############20160316###
###########################
661###############20160317###
###########################
```

I want to split this single file into multiple files based on the the starting string "661" and date (2016MMDD) and rename the split file as 20160315.txt, 20160316.txt and so on. For example each split file will have:

20160315.txt will have:

```
661###############20160315########
################################
################################
```

20160316.txt will have:

```
661###############20160316########
################################
```

20160317.txt will have:

```
661###############20160317#######
###############################
```

Is there an awk command that can do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Split file by pattern](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/298437)

Answer (score 7):

I am sure there is an `awk` command that can do this, I am not skilled enough in `awk` to come up with a solution. In the meantime, you could use something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

csplit -z tosplit /661/ {*}

for file in xx*; do
    newName=$(egrep -o '2[0-9]{7}' $file)
    mv $file $newName.txt
done
rm -rf xx*
```

Where `tosplit` is this file (your example file):

```
661###############20160315###
###########################
###########################
661###############20160316###
###########################
661###############20160317###
###########################
```

After running this script (in the same directory as the `tosplit` file) I get three files:

```
ls 2016031*
20160315.txt  20160316.txt  20160317.txt
```

...looking like this:

```
cat 20160315.txt 
661###############20160315###
###########################
###########################

cat 20160316.txt 
661###############20160316###
###########################

cat 20160317.txt 
661###############20160317###
###########################
```

You can possibly(?) use `csplit` to name the files as well, but that too is above my paygrade!

Comment: Very good for using `csplit`.  You can name the file prefix and, with GNU `csplit`, you can specify an extension format, but you can't do it based on the content of the files, so I doubt this will be improved upon much.  `csplit`, not Awk, *is* the tool for this job.

Comment: @Wildcard Thanks for the comment. I suspected that naming the files based on content would be near impossible with `csplit`, now I know!

Comment: On zsh, I needed to change `{*}` to `"{*}"` to circumvent a failed shell expansion attempt.

Comment: Whenever I need something that seems complicated I think of `awk` and then I come to the Unix zone here and learn about amazingly simple/powerful/useful programs like `column`, `csplit`, etc.  It makes me happy, yet also so sad that I grew up on the $h!tty, capitalistic, scam called DOS instead of a real OS like Unix.

Answer (score 3):

With `awk` something like

```
awk '/^661/{f=substr($0,match($0,/2016[0-9]{4}/),8)".txt"}{print>>f}' file.txt
```

might work for you.

Basicly the parts are:

```
/^661/{...} # on each line starting with 661

match($0,/2016[0-9]{4}/) # find the index of the date (2016MMDD) in current line

substr($0,match($0,/2016[0-9]{4}/),8) # extract the the date in the current line

f=substr($0,match($0,/2016[0-9]{4}/),8)".txt" # assign it to f and append ".txt"

{print>>f} # redirect the content of the current line into the file named by f
```

With a traditional `awk` implementation you might have to replace the *interval expressions* to:

```
awk '/^661/{f=substr($0,match($0,/2016[01][0-9][0-9][0-9]/),8)".txt"}{print>>f}' file.txt
```

Depending on your use case you might also want to change the [behavior of the redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html), i.e. `print>f` vs. `print>>f`.

Comment: This is good to know. Haven't tried this yet, but will give it a try.